# Python (VTK): Connect two 3D points by an oriented cylinder

Tags: python, 3d, geometry, vtk

Consider we have two points in `3D` space, wishing to connect them by a cylinder with specified radius. Apparently the height (length) of cylinder will be the distance between tow two points. However the standard [`Cylinder` object](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/GeometricObjects/Display/Cylinder) has nothing to be oriented to follow the above.

**How to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can see is using `TubeFilter`. Basically you draw a line between the two points and then apply the filter. Here is an [example](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/TubeFilter) in c++, but it should be straightforward to port it to Python.

**EDIT**: And [here](http://www.patinaed.org/sdk/2009/09/vtk-vtktubefilter-example-in-python.html) there's an example in python if that helps.

Comment: Since the post, we searched heavily and finally found a solution which involves calculating orientation angle and rotating the cylinder using `vtk.RotateWXYZ`. They are some tricks, however, it works. The `TubeFilter` solution (which we had also found it useful) is much easier. Therefore this answer is accepted.

Comment: +1000 for `Python` [example](http://www.patinaed.org/sdk/2009/09/vtk-vtktubefilter-example-in-python.html). It is very helpful.